# Lodash uniqWith comparator function modify object properties

Tags: javascript, lodash

I want to modify each object in an array, as well as remove duplicates.  I am already using lodash's uniqWith to compare items so I figured I would do some other logic within the comparator function to modify each item so I can avoid setting up another loop.  Are there any problems with having extra logic within the comparator like below?

```
import uniqWith from 'lodash/uniqWith';

const transformedArray = uniqWith(
    arrayOfObjects,
    (currObject, otherObject): boolean => {

        // modifying current object's properties, is this legit??

        if (<someCondition>) {
            currObject.someProperty = true;
        }

        // actual comparison logic

        if (currObject.uuid === otherObject.uuid) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    },
);
```

Comment: Don't see any outstanding issue with it.  Though as a side note, the bottom part of your method could just be `return currObject.uuid === otherObject.uuid`

Comment: dohh! nice yeah ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`uniqWith`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#uniqWith) documentation only says the following about the callback invocation:

> The comparator is invoked with two arguments: *(arrVal, othVal)*.

I personally wouldn't use the `uniqWith` compare function, for iteration work. The documentation doesn't disclose how often or in what order the compare function will be called. Say you have the array  `[1,2,3]`. I would assume each element is compared against all elements in the output, to check for uniqueness. The implementation might look something like:

```
function uniqWith(array, compareFn) {
  const unique = [];
  for (const current of array) {
    const isDuplicate = unique.some(other => compareFn(current, other));
    if (!isDuplicate) unique.push(current);
  }
  return unique;
}
```

If this is indeed the case that means the callback is never called for `1`, once for `2`, and twice for `3`.

Generally speaking don't use callback functions to do iteration work, unless the function that accepts the callback discloses when/how often/what order etc. this function is called.

Take for example the Array [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method. The documentation discloses all these things.

> `forEach()` calls a provided *`callback`* function once for each element in an array in ascending order. It is not invoked for index properties that have been deleted or are uninitialized. (For sparse arrays, [see example below](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#sparseArray).)

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no, if by "wrong" you mean a breaking issue.

Medium Answer: It shouldn't interfere with the method. Just be aware that doing mutations in unique locations, where you otherwise may not expect them, is trading *clarity* for *brevity*- which can lead to confusion and debugging nightmares later down the road if you lose track of them.

Answer (score 0):

After more thorough testing I realized that there is some optimization done in `lodash/uniqWith` where not every item is necessarily passed to the comparator function as the `currObject`.  So as far as my example code in the original question, it is not guaranteed that every item in array will receive the `.someProperty = true`.  Should've tested this more before posting, but still appreciate the feedback.